# Change user input to read file from command line in python

Tags: python

I would like to change that instead of reading from the user input, it is read from a txt file from the command line

I have the following code:

```
# making the class Graph to illutrate with
# functions and objects
class Graph():
    # conctructor to create number of vertices as graph size
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.V = vertices
        self.graph = [[0 for column in range(vertices)]
                      for row in range(vertices)]

    # helper function printAnswer to print the distance
    def printAnswer(self, dist, src):
        for node in range(self.V):
            if(node != src):
                print("node", src, "to node", node, ":", dist[node])

    # helper function for minimum distance
    def minDistance(self, dist, sptSet):
        # let 1000000009 be the maximum possible value
        min = 1000000009
        # Search not nearest vertex not in the
        # shortest path tree
        for u in range(self.V):
            if dist[u] < min and sptSet[u] == False:
                min = dist[u]
                min_index = u
        # return the min index
        return min_index

    # Function that implements Dijkstra's single source
    # shortest path algorithm for a graph represented
    # using adjacency matrix representation
    def dijkstraMinDist(self, src):
        # full algo for min distance
        dist = [1000000009] * self.V
        dist[src] = 0
        sptSet = [False] * self.V

        for cout in range(self.V):
            # x is always equal to src in first iteration
            x = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet)

            # set this x to true
            sptSet[x] = True

            # Update dist value of the adjacent vertices
            # of the picked vertex only if the current dist
            # is more than new distance
            for y in range(self.V):
                if self.graph[x][y] > 0 and sptSet[y] == False and \
                        dist[y] > dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]:
                    dist[y] = dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]
        # print the answer
        self.printAnswer(dist, src)


# main running of the program
# take input from the user ad create graph
n = int(input())
g = Graph(n)
g.graph = []

# take input of the graph
for i in range(0, n):
    l = list(map(int, input().split()))
    g.graph.append(l)

# call dijkstra for each node
for i in range(0, n):
    g.dijkstraMinDist(i)
```

So, when I run `python3 file.py` the user input is:

```
4
0 2 -1 3
-1 0 1 5
2 3 0 -1
3 -1 4 0
```

and the output is:

```
node 0 to node 1 : 2
node 0 to node 2 : 3
```

And I would like to run from the command line `python3 input.txt output.txt` with a text file with n in the first line and the matrix in the next lines separeted by spaces and have the output in a text file too, thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Show your own effort (code) properly formatted in the question. First you must get the command line arguments, open and read the input file and finally open and write to the output file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Reading user input from a file is common and well-tutorialized task. You should do some of your own research on how to do this before asking here. If you have any issues trying to adapt online tutorials to your usecase, feel free to ask here and we'll be happy to help. Read through this article for more advice on writing good questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in `sys.argv[]` list.

Example:

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])
g = Graph(n)
g.graph = []

for i in range(0, n):
    l = list(map(int, sys.argv[2].split()))
    g.graph.append(l)

for i in range(0, n):
    g.dijkstraMinDist(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 54, in <module>
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'input.txt'

Comment: @ChristianYisus how did you execute it? what are the parameters/arguments? show your full code because obviously your code is not what you posted here since it has 54 or more lines and the one you posted is only 10 lines. add a screenshot of the error with the relevant line highlighted in your code into your question.

Comment: I just edit the code, thanks.